# How to toggle many values at once / values are in a list?

Tags: javascript, logic

Is there an efficient way to toggle the Boolean value of multiple variables at once? My variables are lines that I want to show/hide depending on userValue.

```
myList = [lineA, lineB, lineC, lineD]
```

My example below is very hard-coded. There is a lot of repeated code. Is there a smarter way to do this?

```
if (userValue == 'A') {
    lineA.visible = true;
    lineB.visible = false;
    lineC.visible = false;
    lineD.visible = false;
} else if (userValue == 'B') {
    lineA.visible = false;
    lineB.visible = true;
    lineC.visible = false;
    lineD.visible = false;
} else if (userValue == 'C') {
    lineA.visible = false;
    lineB.visible = false;
    lineC.visible = true;
    lineD.visible = false;
} else if (userValue == 'D') {
    lineA.visible = false;
    lineB.visible = false;
    lineC.visible = false;
    lineD.visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A switch-case would be better:

```
//initialize to false
lineA.visible = false;
lineB.visible = false;
lineC.visible = false;
lineD.visible = false;

switch(userValue ) {
  case 'A':
    lineA.visible = true;
    break;
   case 'B':
    lineB.visible = true;
    break;
 case 'C':
    lineC.visible = true;
    break;
 case 'D':
    lineD.visible = true;
    break;
  default:
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const lines = [lineA, lineB, lineC, lineD];
const userInputs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

// Reset visible states for all lines
for (line of lines) {
    line.visible = false;
}

// Set visible = true for specific line, picked by entered userValue
lines[userInputs.indexOf(userValue)].visible = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two arrays one array of letter and second array of lines. Loop through lines array and change all to `false`. Then get the index of `userValue` from array of letters and change the line at that index by changing `visible` to `true`

```
const arr = ['A','B','C','D']
const objs = [lineA,lineB,lineC,lineD];
objs.forEach(x => x.visible = false)

let index = arr.indexOf(userValue);
obj[index].visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for the values and an array for the lines. Then iterate and set `visible` with the result of the check.

```
var userValue = 'A',
    values = { A: lineA, B: lineB, C: lineC, D: lineD },
    userObject = values[userValue],
    lines = [lineA, lineB, lineC, lineD];

lines.forEach(line => line.visible = line === userObject);
```

Comment: You need set `false` by default for all items

Comment: @luther, do i miss something? it is setting `false` to all items who have not the actual value.

Comment: We don't know about current state of items.

Comment: the condition returns always either `true` or `false`. the old state is overwritten by this value.